# how to sort a column in excel using c# InvokeMember property?

Tags: c#, excel, late-binding

I'm using c# `InvokeMember` property to generate excel. I need to sort the 1st column(A) which is of type - `DATE`. The following code throwing this exception:

> Sort method of Range class failed

Let me know what is wrong in the following code.

```
object oRng = oSheet.GetType().InvokeMember(Properties.Resources.Range, BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, oSheet, new object[] { "A1", "A1"});
object oRows = oRng.GetType().InvokeMember(Properties.Resources.Rows, BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, oRng, null);
oRows.GetType().InvokeMember("Sort", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, oRows, null);
```